# Excel Macro for changing references with numbers separated by a dash into the full set of references

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I have been dealing with customer bill of materials that contains references with numbers that are separated by a dash, rather than the full sequence of references spelled out, e.g. C1-4 instead of C1, C2, C3, C4 or C1 C2 C3 C4

Some customers will use a comma to separate references, some only space, sometimes there is a mix of the two, which also complicates things. Here is an example:

```
   R161-169
 
   R2 R5, R7 R11

   R103-7
   
   R26 R28-30 R42, R45-46, R62-65, R70-71, R92-102, R113-114
   
   R31-35 R40-41 R56-61 R72-79 R86-91
   
   R36, R38-39
```

I'm trying to make a macro that will generate the full set of references automatically for only the selected portion of the references column, and generate that full set of references in the column next to it.

*Sometimes customers leave a blank line between sections of references. Empty cells should remain empty in the output.*

I found one place online that had asked a very similar question - https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/splitting-out-numbers-separated-by-dash.679290/ but I did not understand the code there and it did not work for what I've been trying to do.

I am not great with VBS, but I got the below code running without throwing any errors so far, but it doesn't generate the full set of references. It just copies them as they are, and I do not know where I went wrong.

```
Sub SplitReferences()
'June 1, 2023
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim outputCell As Range
Dim inputArea As Range
Dim inputCell As Range
Dim startNum As Long
Dim endNum As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim outputString As String

' Set the input range where your values are
Set inputRange = Selection ' Use the selected range as input

' Set the output range where you want the split references
Set outputCell = inputRange.Offset(0, 1).Cells(1) ' Output in the column next to the input

' Loop through each area in the input range
For Each inputArea In inputRange.Areas
    ' Loop through each cell in the area
    For Each inputCell In inputArea
        ' Split the value by dash
        Dim parts() As String
        parts = Split(inputCell.Value, "-")

        ' Check if there is a dash in the value
        If UBound(parts) > 0 Then
            ' Extract the start and end numbers
            startNum = Val(parts(0))
            endNum = Val(parts(1))
        Else
            ' If there is no dash, treat it as a single value
            startNum = Val(parts(0))
            endNum = Val(parts(0))
        End If

        ' Loop through the numbers and add them to the output range
        For i = startNum To endNum
            outputCell.Value = inputCell.Offset(i - startNum).Value
            Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(1) ' Move to the next row
        Next i
    Next inputCell
Next inputArea
End Sub
```

Comment: To help please show sample data and also with  the expected outcome, it is unclear for example if **R26 R28-30 R42, R45-46, R62-65, R70-71, R92-102, R113-114** is in one cell or are they in individual cells? With the output do you want them all in one cell or individual cells?

Comment: The references you mentioned are all in one cell. The output should also be in the cell next to it as R26 R28 R29 R30, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim c As Range, arr, el, txt As String, rv As String, sep As String
    
    For Each c In Selection.Cells 'loop selected range
        txt = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(txt) > 0 Then      'cell has a value?
            arr = Split(Normalize(txt), " ")
            rv = ""
            sep = ""
            For Each el In arr
                'convert to sequence if value has a dash
                If InStr(el, "-") > 0 Then el = Sequence(CStr(el), " ")
                If Len(el) > 0 Then rv = rv & sep & el
                sep = " "
            Next el
            With c.Offset(0, 1)
                .WrapText = True
                .Value = rv
                .EntireRow.AutoFit
            End With
        End If 'has content
    Next c
End Sub

'Normalize the input to replace unwanted characters with spaces
'  Remove runs of >1 space, and spaces around "-"
Function Normalize(ByVal txt As String)
    Dim arr, el
    arr = Array(vbLf, vbCr, Chr(160), ",", ";", ":") 'replace these with a space
    For Each el In arr
        txt = Replace(txt, el, " ")
    Next el
    Do While InStr(1, txt, "  ") > 0  'remove any multi-space runs
        txt = Replace(txt, "  ", " ")
    Loop
    txt = Replace(txt, " -", "-") 'remove any spaces next to dashes
    txt = Replace(txt, "- ", "-")
    Normalize = txt
End Function

'Return a sequence from a pattern like [letter][number1]-[number2],
'  separated by `sep`
Function Sequence(txt As String, sep As String)
    Dim prefix, rv As String, sp, arr, v1, v2, i As Long
    prefix = GetPrefix(txt) 'extract leading non-numeric character(s)
    arr = Split(txt, "-")
    v1 = NumberOnly(arr(0))
    v2 = NumberOnly(arr(1))
    If Len(v1) > 0 And Len(v2) > 0 Then
        'handle case like R102-4, R102-24
        If Len(v2) < Len(v1) Then v2 = Left(v1, Len(v1) - Len(v2)) & v2
        v1 = CLng(v1)
        v2 = CLng(v2)
        For i = v1 To v2 'assumes V2 > v1...
            rv = rv & sp & prefix & i
            sp = sep
        Next i
    End If
    Sequence = rv
End Function

'return the first [whole] number found in `txt`
Function NumberOnly(txt)
    Dim i As Long, c, rv
    For i = 1 To Len(txt)
        c = Mid(txt, i, 1)
        If c Like "#" Then
            NumberOnly = NumberOnly & c
        Else
            If Len(NumberOnly) > 0 Then Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function

'Return leading non-numeric character(s)
Function GetPrefix(txt As String)
    Dim i As Long, c As String, rv
    For i = 1 To Len(txt)
        c = Mid(txt, i, 1)
        If c Like "#" Then Exit For
        rv = rv & c
    Next i
    GetPrefix = rv
End Function
```

Comment: This works! Thank you very much! Is it possible to add a Wrap Text at the end so the references don't bleed over into the next column?

Comment: Yes you can add that no problem.

Comment: I'm trying to tack on
     Range(Selection).WrapText = True
    Range(Selection).EntireRow.AutoFit 

But it's not modifying the output

Comment: See edits above

Comment: That works perfectly, what a delight! Thank you, thank you, and thank you again :)

Comment: Oh no, Tim! I have noticed an unwanted effect in one of my tests - A blank cell in the selection will not be blank in the output, but is filled in with the data from the cell above it. An empty cell in the selection should also be empty in the output.

Comment: Augh. One more problem. Sometimes references will begin with a string of letters. eg. CR1-6 or DISP1-2. I just noticed that the output only does the first letter in these cases. I see that the code says it assumes a single letter prefix, I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that this might not be the case.  :(

Comment: See updates above

Comment: It works exactly as I hoped it would now :) Superb, I thank you for your patience :)

Comment: Glitch: Designators with multiple numerical digits that say e.g. R102-4 will NOT generate R102 R103 R104. It looks like the macro doesn't understand it and will skip it entirely. I am worried that if that's fixed it would generate all references from R4 to R102

Comment: The function which create the sequences would have a problem with `R102-4`, since it's expecting complete numbers.  You'd need to add some more logic for cases like that where the second number is "less" than the first.  You'd also need to handle (eg) cases like `R102-16`.  If the length of `v2` is less then that of `v1` then add the first [difference in length] characters from `v1` to the front of `v2` before converting to `Long`.  See edit above

Answer (score 1):

This is a UDF version that does what you ask

```
Public Function SplitReferences(aRange As Variant) As Variant

Dim sOutput As String, sInput As String
Dim sPl As Variant, sPl2 As Variant, J1 As Variant, J2 As Variant
Dim I As Long, J As Long

If TypeName(aRange) = "Range" And aRange.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    sOutput = ""
    sInput = aRange
    sInput = Trim(Replace(aRange, ",", " "))
    sPl = Split(sInput, " ")
    For I = LBound(sPl) To UBound(sPl)
        If InStr(sPl(I), "-") = 0 Then
            sOutput = sOutput & sPl(I) & " "
        Else
            sPl2 = Split(sPl(I), "-")
            If UBound(sPl2) - LBound(sPl2) = 1 Then
                J1 = Replace(sPl2(LBound(sPl2)), "R", "")
                J2 = sPl2(UBound(sPl2))
                If IsNumeric(J1) And IsNumeric(J2) Then
                    For J = CLng(J1) To CLng(J2)
                        sOutput = sOutput & "R" & J & " "
                    Next J
                Else
                    SplitReferences = CVErr(xlErrValue)
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Else
                SplitReferences = CVErr(xlErrValue)
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next I
    SplitReferences = sOutput
Else
    SplitReferences = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End If
```

End Function

A UDF is still a function, you can use it however you want.
With this code you could, for example, process the range A1:A400 and write the result in column B.

```
Sub DoThis()
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    
    For Each Cell In Range("A1:A400").Cells
        Cell.Offset(0, 1) = SplitReferences(Cell)
    Next Cell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this needs to run on more than one cell, either the whole column or a selection of a column. So a UDF will not work for what I need to do. If this can be changed into a macro that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

YAA

```
Private Sub ParseCell()
' Set the input range where your values are
Dim inputRange As Range, outputCell As Range, inputArea As Range
Dim inputCell As Variant
Dim startNum As Long, endNum As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim resList  As String
Debug.Print "Selection_change"

Set inputRange = Selection ' Use the selected range as input

' Set the output range where you want the split references
Set outputCell = inputRange.Offset(0, 1).Cells(1) ' Output in the column next to the input

    ' Loop through each area in the input range
    resList = ""
    For Each inputArea In inputRange.Areas
        ' Loop through each cell in the area
        For Each inputCell In inputArea
            Set outputCell = inputCell.Offset(0, 1).Cells(1)
            ' Split the value by dash
            Dim parts() As String
            
            resList = ""
            If Len(inputCell.Value) > 0 Then
                parts = Split(Replace(inputCell.Value, ",", " "), " ")
                For i = LBound(parts) To UBound(parts)
                    If Len(Trim(parts(i))) > 0 Then
                        resList = resList & ExpandCellsList(Trim(parts(i))) & " "
                    End If
                Next i
                If Len(resList) > 0 Then resList = Left(resList, Len(resList) - 1)
            End If
            Debug.Print outputCell.Address, resList
            outputCell.Value = resList
        Next inputCell
    Next inputArea
End Sub

Public Function ExpandCellsList(cl As String) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim sH As String, sv1 As String, sv2 As String
Dim startNum As Long, endNum As Long
Dim res As String
    i = InStr(1, cl, "-")
    If i > 0 Then
        sv2 = Trim(Mid(cl, i + 1))
        sH = Trim(Left(cl, i - 1))
        For i = 1 To Len(sH)
            If InStr(1, "01234567890", Mid(sH, i, 1)) > 0 Then
                sv1 = Trim(Mid(sH, i))
                sH = Trim(Left(sH, i - 1))
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If Len(sv2) < Len(sv1) Then
            sv2 = Left(sv1, Len(sv1) - Len(sv2)) & sv2
        End If
        startNum = Val(sv1)
        endNum = Val(sv2)
        If endNum > startNum Then
            For i = startNum To endNum
                res = res & sH & CStr(i) & " "
            Next i
        End If
        If Len(res) > 0 Then res = Left(res, Len(res) - 1)
        ExpandCellsList = res
    Else
        ExpandCellsList = cl
    End If
End Function
```

Result example

| InputCells | OutputCells |
| --- | --- |
| R161-169 | R161 R162 R163 R164 R165 R166 R167 R168 R169 |
| R2 R5 R7 R11 | R2 R5 R7 R11 |
| R26 R28-30 R42, R45-46, R62-65, R70-71, R92-102, R113-114 | R26 R28 R29 R30 R42 R45 R46 R62 R63 R64 R65 R70 R71 R92 R93 R94 R95 R96 R97 R98 R99 R100 R101 R102 R113 R114 |
| R31-35 R40-41 R56-61 R72-79 R86-91 | R31 R32 R33 R34 R35 R40 R41 R56 R57 R58 R59 R60 R61 R72 R73 R74 R75 R76 R77 R78 R79 R86 R87 R88 R89 R90 R91 |
| R36, R38-39 | R36 R38 R39 |

Comment: Thank you very much! This macro works, but there is one glitch: Designators with multiple numerical digits e.g. R102-4 will NOT generate R102 R103 R104. It looks like the macro doesn't understand it and will skip it entirely. I am worried that if that's fixed it would generate all references from R4 to R102

Comment: function test ``If endNum > startNum`` Then <generate> Else <nothing to do>.R102-4  is an ambiguous case. Can generate R102 R103 R104 or R4 ...R102. By example R90-2 ->R90..R92. You can explain possible combinations.

Comment: Answer updated for this case.

Comment: Oh no, when the whole references column is selected, it goes into an infinite loop. Otherwise it works perfectly

Comment: I have noticed an unwanted effect in one of my tests - A blank cell in the selection will not be blank in the output, but is filled in with the data from the cell above it. An empty cell in the selection should also be empty in the output.