# Expanding references separated by a dash

Tags: excel, vba

I have been dealing with customer bill of materials that contains reference designators with numbers that are separated by a dash, rather than the full sequence of references spelled out, e.g. C1-4 instead of C1 C2 C3 C4

I've been working with the below VBA code for a while now. I've got it pretty close to doing what I want it to, but I recently discovered that dashed references including the type character, like C32-C35 or CR8-CR10, are not understood - they are simply skipped by the code and not included in the output column. Obviously that was not good, fortunately I have an error finding process later on that caught the missing references.

Also I thought I had it set so that the rows in the new output column that become populated with many additional references would resize in height to accommodate them, but that is not working.

Any help with those two problems would be much appreciated.

Notes: Some customers will use a comma to separate references, some only a space, sometimes there is a mix of the two. This is already accounted for in the existing code and works well. Sometimes customers leave a blank line between sections of references, which may complicates things. Empty cells should remain empty in the output. This is also working well in the existing code. Here is an example of the customer references:

```
  CR8-CR10, CR21
  CR161-169
  (blank line)
  R2, R5, R7-R11
  R103-7
  R26 R28-30 R42, R45-46, R62-65, R70-71, R92-102, R113-114
  C32-C35
  R31-35 R40-41 R56-61 R72-79 R86-91
  (blank line)
  LED1-4, 6-8
  XTAL1-3
```

What I want is a VBA macro that will generate the full set of references automatically for the selected portion of the references column, generate that full set of references into a new column next to it, and then resize the cell heights to fit the expanded references.

So the output I'm looking for is:

```
  CR8 CR9 CR10 CR21
  CR161 CR162 CR163 CR164 CR165 CR166 CR167 CR168 CR169
  (Blank line)
  R2 R5 R7 R8 R9 R10 R11
  R103 R104 R105 R106 R107
etc.
```

Example pictures of references and output:

[image: Example Original References]

[image: Example References and Output]

My current VBA code:

```
'Any references separated by a dash, like R22-28, are separated out into the full string of references.
'
'Select all cells with references and run the macro. The macro will not alter the original column
'of references, it will create a new column to the right and put the expanded references there.
'
'Any cells with references that intentionally have a dash, or an underscore, and / or is otherwise
'a non-standard sequence of numeric references (like some COMP parts), may need to be changed or added
'manually. They should be double-checked after the macro has been run.
'Alternately, don't select them and copy / paste them afterwards.
'
'updated June 30, 2023

Dim sH As String       'Added
Sub ExpandDashedReferences()
'Input from ValNik on SO, June 2, 2023
'Added by Black Cat on SO, June 14, 2023
'
'Set the input range where your values are
Dim inputRange As Range, outputCell As Range, inputArea As Range
Dim inputCell As Variant
Dim startNum As Long, endNum As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim resList  As String
Debug.Print "Selection_change"

Set inputRange = Selection.Columns(1) ' Added Use the selected range as input
    
    'Insert a new column to the right
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    
' Set the output range where you want the split references
Set outputCell = inputRange.Offset(0, 1).Cells(1) ' Output in the column next to the input

    ' Loop through each area in the input range
    resList = ""
    For Each inputArea In inputRange.Areas
        ' Loop through each cell in the area
        For Each inputCell In inputArea
            Set outputCell = inputCell.Offset(0, 1).Cells(1)
            ' Split the value by dash
            Dim parts() As String
            If Len(inputCell.Value) > 0 Then
                resList = ""
            ElseIf Len(inputCell.Value) = 0 Then ' blank cell
                Debug.Print "blank"
                'the same as previous
                'resList = resList
            ElseIf IsEmpty(inputCell) Then
                Debug.Print "empty"
                resList = ""
            End If
            If Len(inputCell.Value) > 0 Then
                parts = Split(Replace(inputCell.Value, ",", " "), " ")
                For i = LBound(parts) To UBound(parts)
                    If Len(Trim(parts(i))) > 0 Then
                        resList = resList & ExpandCellsList(Trim(parts(i))) & " "
                    End If
                Next i
                If Len(resList) > 0 Then resList = Left(resList, Len(resList) - 1): outputCell.Value = resList  'Moved here
            End If
            Debug.Print outputCell.Address, resList
        Next inputCell
    Next inputArea
End Sub

Public Function ExpandCellsList(cl As String) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim sv1 As String, sv2 As String, shdepo As String   'Added
Dim startNum As Long, endNum As Long
Dim res As String
    i = InStr(1, cl, "-")
    If i > 0 Then
        sv2 = Trim(Mid(cl, i + 1))
        shdepo = sH
        sH = Trim(Left(cl, i - 1))
        For i = 1 To Len(sH)
            If InStr(1, "01234567890", Mid(sH, i, 1)) > 0 Then
                sv1 = Trim(Mid(sH, i))
                sH = Trim(Left(sH, i - 1))
                If Len(sH) = 0 Then sH = shdepo   'Added
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If Len(sv2) < Len(sv1) Then
            sv2 = Left(sv1, Len(sv1) - Len(sv2)) & sv2
        End If
        startNum = Val(sv1)
        endNum = Val(sv2)
        If endNum > startNum Then
            For i = startNum To endNum
                res = res & sH & CStr(i) & " "
            Next i
        End If
        If Len(res) > 0 Then res = Left(res, Len(res) - 1)
        ExpandCellsList = res
    Else
        sH = Left(Trim(cl), 1)    'Added
        ExpandCellsList = cl
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: An image of the original data and one of the expected output would be welcome. The height depents of the width...

Comment: I have added a picture, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Don't add as a picture - we won't type it out just to then type out functions as well, post data that can be copied.

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76391039/excel-macro-for-changing-references-with-numbers-separated-by-a-dash-into-the-fu/76391910#76391910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of tweaks to my previous answer (which already had the row resizing):

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim c As Range, arr, el, txt As String, rv As String, sep As String
    
    For Each c In Selection.Cells 'loop selected range
        txt = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(txt) > 0 Then      'cell has a value?
            arr = Split(Normalize(txt), " ")
            rv = ""
            sep = ""
            GetPrefix ""   'clear the last cell's prefix
            For Each el In arr
                'convert to sequence if value has a dash
                If InStr(el, "-") > 0 Then
                    el = Sequence(CStr(el), " ")
                Else
                    GetPrefix CStr(el) 'if single value, remember the prefix...
                End If
                If Len(el) > 0 Then rv = rv & sep & el
                sep = " "
            Next el
            With c.Offset(0, 1)
                .WrapText = True
                .Value = rv
                .EntireRow.AutoFit
            End With
        End If 'has content
    Next c
End Sub

'Normalize the input to replace unwanted characters with spaces
'  Remove runs of >1 space, and spaces around "-"
Function Normalize(ByVal txt As String)
    Dim arr, el
    arr = Array(vbLf, vbCr, Chr(160), ",", ";", ":") 'replace these with a space
    For Each el In arr
        txt = Replace(txt, el, " ")
    Next el
    Do While InStr(1, txt, "  ") > 0  'remove any multi-space runs
        txt = Replace(txt, "  ", " ")
    Loop
    txt = Replace(txt, " -", "-") 'remove any spaces next to dashes
    txt = Replace(txt, "- ", "-")
    Normalize = txt
End Function

'Return a sequence from a pattern like [letter][number1]-[number2],
'  separated by `sep`
Function Sequence(txt As String, sep As String)
    Dim prefix, rv As String, sp, arr, v1, v2, i As Long
    prefix = GetPrefix(txt) 'extract leading non-numeric character(s)
    arr = Split(txt, "-")
    v1 = NumberOnly(arr(0))
    v2 = NumberOnly(arr(1))
    If Len(v1) > 0 And Len(v2) > 0 Then
        'handle case like R102-4, R102-24
        If Len(v2) < Len(v1) Then v2 = Left(v1, Len(v1) - Len(v2)) & v2
        v1 = CLng(v1)
        v2 = CLng(v2)
        For i = v1 To v2 'assumes V2 > v1...
            rv = rv & sp & prefix & i
            sp = sep
        Next i
    End If
    Sequence = rv
End Function

'return the first [whole] number found in `txt`
Function NumberOnly(txt)
    Dim i As Long, c, rv
    For i = 1 To Len(txt)
        c = Mid(txt, i, 1)
        If c Like "#" Then
            NumberOnly = NumberOnly & c
        Else
            If Len(NumberOnly) > 0 Then Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function

'Return leading non-numeric character(s)
'   Remember the last one returned (for input cases like "LED1-4, 6-8")
'   Clear the cached prefix by calling `GetPrefix ""`
Function GetPrefix(txt As String) As String
    Static lastPrefix 'for caching the last prefix returned
    Dim i As Long, c As String, rv As String
    If Len(txt) = 0 Then
        lastPrefix = "" 'pass in an empty string to clear the cached value
    Else
        For i = 1 To Len(txt)
            c = Mid(txt, i, 1)
            If c Like "#" Then Exit For
            rv = rv & c
        Next i
        If Len(rv) = 0 And Len(lastPrefix) > 0 Then rv = lastPrefix 'if empty use cached...
        lastPrefix = rv 'remember this one...
        GetPrefix = rv
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the help again! I did a test run with your tweaked code and it worked just like I was expecting, except in one case: I had one cell with C3, C5, 9-11 and the output was C3 C5 9 10 11 the last three numbers were without the C prefix. I thought it was odd considering that everything else in the output looked perfect.

Comment: Fixed that with an edit to `Tester`  Was not remembering the prefix it it was only a single value and not a range.

Comment: Excellent, your edit works for C3, C5, 9-11
I was trying to remember why I had switched from using your code from June 2, It's because yours doesn't create a new column to put the output into. I'll just make sure to make a new column before running it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
   Call seriesGenerator(Me.Range("H1:H11"))
End Sub

Public Sub seriesGenerator(source As Range)
   Dim r As Range, s As String, ltrs As String, c As Long, v As Variant
   Dim serial As String, p As Long, idx As Long, fromIdx As Long, toIdx As Long
   Dim sfrom As String, sto As String, lnfrom As Long, lnto As Long, tmp As Long
   If source Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   For Each r In source
      s = Trim(r.value)
      If s = vbNullString Then GoTo Continue
      ltrs = getLetters(s)
      If ltrs = vbNullString Then GoTo Continue
      s = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(Replace(s, ",", " "), ltrs, ""))
      v = Split(s, " ")
      serial = vbNullString
      For c = 0 To UBound(v)
         p = InStr(1, v(c), "-")
         If p > 0 Then
            sfrom = Trim(Left(v(c), p - 1)): lnfrom = Len(sfrom)
            sto = Trim(Mid$(v(c), p + 1)):   lnto = Len(sto)
            If lnto < lnfrom Then
               sto = Left(sfrom, lnfrom - lnto) & sto
            End If
         
            fromIdx = CLng(sfrom)
            toIdx = CLng(sto)
            If fromIdx > toIdx Then
               tmp = fromIdx:    fromIdx = toIdx:  toIdx = tmp
            End If
            For idx = fromIdx To toIdx
               serial = serial & " " & ltrs & idx
            Next
         Else
            serial = serial & " " & ltrs & v(c)
         End If
      Next
      r.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Trim(serial)
Continue:
   Next
   With source.Offset(0, 1)
      .WrapText = True
      .rows.AutoFit
   End With
End Sub

Private Function getLetters(s As String) As String
   Dim c As Long, ln As Long, ccode As Integer
   ln = Len(s)
   For c = 1 To ln
      ccode = Asc(Mid$(s, c, 1))
      If (ccode >= 48 And ccode <= 57) Then Exit Function
      getLetters = getLetters & Chr$(ccode)
   Next
   MsgBox ("Ubnormal format> " & s)
End Function
```

[image]

**This version can be used from within a cell or from VBA**
=seriesGenerator(H1)  or call seriesGenerator(H1:H11)

```vb
Public Function seriesGenerator(source As Range) As Variant
   Dim r As Range, s As String, ltrs As String, c As Long, v As Variant
   Dim serial As String, p As Long, idx As Long, fromIdx As Long, toIdx As Long
   Dim sfrom As String, sto As String, lnfrom As Long, lnto As Long, tmp As Long, fromCell As Boolean
   If source Is Nothing Then Exit Function
   fromCell = TypeName(Application.Caller) = "Range"
   For Each r In source
      s = Trim(r.value)
      If s = vbNullString Then GoTo Continue
      ltrs = getLetters(s)
      If ltrs = vbNullString Then GoTo Continue
      s = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(Replace(s, ",", " "), ltrs, ""))
      v = Split(s, " ")
      serial = vbNullString
      For c = 0 To UBound(v)
         p = InStr(1, v(c), "-")
         If p > 0 Then
            sfrom = Left(v(c), p - 1): lnfrom = Len(sfrom)
            sto = Mid$(v(c), p + 1):   lnto = Len(sto)
            If lnto < lnfrom Then
               sto = Left(sfrom, lnfrom - lnto) & sto
            End If
         
            fromIdx = CLng(sfrom)
            toIdx = CLng(sto)
            If fromIdx > toIdx Then
               tmp = fromIdx:    fromIdx = toIdx:  toIdx = tmp
            End If
            For idx = fromIdx To toIdx
               serial = serial & " " & ltrs & idx
            Next
         Else
            serial = serial & " " & ltrs & v(c)
         End If
      Next
      If fromCell Then
         seriesGenerator = Trim(serial)
      Else
         r.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Trim(serial)
      End If
Continue:
   Next
   If fromCell = False Then
      With source.Offset(0, 1)
         .WrapText = True
         .rows.AutoFit
      End With
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is helpful for you.

```
Sub demo()
    Dim sKey As String, rngData As Range
    Dim res, arr
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim sStart As String, sEnd As String
    Dim iStart As Integer, iEnd As Integer
    Set rngData = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    arr = rngData.Value
    res = arr
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        res(i, 1) = ""
        If Len(Trim(arr(i, 1))) > 0 Then
            txt = Replace(Replace(arr(i, 1), " ", ","), ",,", ",")
            For Each itm In Split(txt, ",")
                If VBA.InStr(itm, "-") Then
                    brr = Split(itm, "-")
                    If Not VBA.IsNumeric(Left(brr(0), 1)) Then sKey = sGetKey(brr(0))
                    sStart = Replace(brr(0), sKey, "")
                    sEnd = Replace(brr(1), sKey, "")
                    iStart = Val(sStart)
                    iEnd = Val(sEnd)
                    If iEnd < iStart Then
                        ' the following line works well for R103-7.
                        ' I'm not sure if it covers all typical scenario
                        iEnd = Val(Left(sStart, Len(sStart) - Len(sEnd)) & sEnd)
                    End If
                    For j = iStart To iEnd
                        res(i, 1) = res(i, 1) & " " & sKey & j
                    Next
                Else
                    res(i, 1) = res(i, 1) & " " & itm
                End If
            Next
        End If
        res(i, 1) = Mid(res(i, 1), 2)
    Next
    rngData.Offset(0, 1).Value = res
End Sub

Function sGetKey(sItem) As String
    For i = 1 To Len(sItem)
        If VBA.IsNumeric(Mid(sItem, i, 1)) Then Exit For
    Next
    If i > 1 Then sGetKey = Left(sItem, i - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: if exist R103-7 maybe exist and R147-67.... => 147\10=14*10=140+67=207!

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ You are right. That's the reason for the comment in my code. I'm not sure what's the typical scenario.

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ I have updated the code. I think it covers the scenario which is mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, your code gives me "Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch"

Comment: @WhiteLancer64 May I know the line number of error? The code was tested before post.

Comment: The debugger flagged     For i = 1 To UBound(arr)

Comment: @WhiteLancer64 If column A is blank or only cell A1 has content, `arr` is not an array anymore. Then you will get "Run-time error '13'".